# Monotouch Condtitional Compilation for Distribution

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, preprocessor-directive

I'm aware you can include directives to compile and run different code based on whether you're  in debug or release mode.  Can you do the same sort of thing when you build the project for distribution?

I ask because I've just submitted and had approved an app update which points to a web service on our test server rather than live!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you sure can.

In MonoDevelop under Project Options->Compiler->Define Symbols, choose the appropriate build configuration (AppStore), and you can make a new variable such as `PRODUCTION`.

You can then use:

```
#if PRODUCTION
#endif
```

Throughout your code.